# How to make bottom bar as given in image using angular material or angular?

Tags: html, css, angular-material, angular7

I'm creating angular 7 application and designing UI. i want to fix bottom bar like below shown in image. only required middle circular icon leave that other thing. 
[here is the bottom bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb1cd.png)

Comment: What problem are you having with your implementation?

Comment: i unable to make bottom bar given above in image.

Comment: Is your question how to fix the bar on the bottom? I think nobody does understand your question right.

Comment: You need to add more details please
what have you tried?
Where are you facing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom component using mat-toolbar, fab-button, a div and styling:

Component template:

```
<div class="fab-wrapper">
  <button mat-button mat-fab>
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Component SASS:

```
:host {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -36px;

  .fab-wrapper {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    position: relative;
    top: 36px;
    left: calc(50% - 36px);
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 36px;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

This should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: this css used, the center circle white bottom border fine but top border i don't want, bcoz top border hide top other UI part or cut some UI part above the center circle.

Comment: Then feel free to change it. The example should give you enough to work with so that you can make it work the way you need.